# Connect to SOCKS server

Tags: android, socks

**What i have:** Right now i am using this code to connect to the SOCKS proxy server through my application.

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost", "192.168.1.202");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort", "1080");
```

**What it does:** This code actually sends request to the SOCKS server and if i see logs then it says ***Accept*** first and then ***Connect***, but in the same line gives error in the connection.

**What i want:** i want a simple method to connect to SOCKS server. I have tried alot and found the above brief working stuff that atleast sends something to the SOCKS server.

Anybody any idea then please give me some code example for the request.